# Plotting multiple datasets with react-chartjs-2 on a single graph

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs

I am using Line chart from react-chartjs-2.  I want to create multiple line charts in the same graph for different users (X- date range for 90 days, Y axis- percentages)

```
User 1
70%    Jul-18
68%    Jul-24
72%    Jul-30
75%    Aug-11
63%    Aug-14
72%    Aug-31

User 2
80%   Jul-01
64%   Jul-15
78%   Sep-03
83%   Sep-15
```

so user1 has 6 values to be plotted and User2 has 4 values both with different dates. Is is possible to do this with LineChart in react-chartjs-2?